# Can I change mongoose schema type ObjectId to string?

Tags: mongoose

I've decided to use the least often possible ObjectId in my mongoose schema. Mostly because they are annoying (`model.toJson()` still doesn't give me a string!?!).

Assuming I have 2 models: Post and Comment as follows:

```js
import { Schema } from "mongoose"
// Not stored directly in the database, only inside the "post" array.
const comment = new Schema({
   message: String   
})

const post = new Schema({
  content: String,
  comments: [comment]
})
```

Would I be able to not create a schema for comment and put it directly in `post` schema like so (without breaking my architecture and keeping the `_id` as a String instead:

```js
const post = new Schema({
  content: String,
  comments: {
    type: [{_id:String, message: String}],
    default: []
  }
})
```

*Note: in the comments, `_id` was `Schema.Types.ObjectId` before, but now it's a `String`*

Answer (score 0):

You *can* have an _id of type string but you will need to fill it in yourself.
You can use the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package or put the unix epoch timestamp of the comment creation with the user id in a string (assuming there is some kind of user in your app) and it should work just fine (dk if something like this is bad practice tho).

The schemas would look like this

```js
const comment = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  message: String
})

const post = new Schema({
  content: String,
  comments: [comment]
})
```

Adding a comment to a post would look something like this

```js
await PostModel.update(
  {_id: <post_id>},
  {$push: {comments: {_id: uuidv4(), message: "Hello!"}}}
)
```

You can even skip having an id on your comments entirely by adding an option object with _id: false after the fields definition

```js
const comment = new Schema({
    message: String
  },
  {
    _id: false
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Xerxis. I have pre-existing data in my database. Would changing from `Schema.Types.ObjectID` to `String` break the ids ?

Comment: No, collection needs to be dropped and recreated but you can easily make a script to get all the documents and copy them in the new collection.